# PHP posted time ago based on midnight 12.00 AM

Tags: php, date, datetime

I've custom news module, where I've the publish date. I want to display the posted hours ago based on the publish date. Suppose posted time is 08.00 PM and now its 09.00 PM, then I want to display posted 1 hour ago. But after 11.59 PM on the same day, I need to display the posted date. Until 11.59 PM, it should display "posted 4 hours ago" after 11.59 PM, I need to display the posted date.

How can I calculate the time ago function based on the midnight 12.00 AM time? I used the following code, but it always calculating 24hours from the posted date and time.

```
$time = time() - $postedTime;
$time = ($time<1)? 1 : $time;
$tokens = array (
    31536000 => 'Year',
    2592000 => 'Month',
    604800 => 'Week',
    86400 => 'Day',
    3600 => 'Hour',
    60 => 'Minute',
    1 => 'Second'
);

foreach ($tokens as $unit => $text) {
    if ($time < $unit) continue;
    $numberOfUnits = floor($time / $unit);

    if($time>86400) {
        return date('d.m.Y', $timestamp);
    } else{
       return $numberOfUnits.' '.$text.(($numberOfUnits>1)?'s':'');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I edit your code a bit.

```
$postedMidNight = strtotime('midnight '.date('y-m-d',$postedTime))+ 86400 ;
foreach ($tokens as $unit => $text) {
    if ($time < $unit)
        continue;
    $numberOfUnits = floor($time / $unit);

    if (time() > $postedMidNight) {
        return date('d.m.Y', $timestamp);
    } else {
        return $numberOfUnits . ' ' . $text . (($numberOfUnits > 1) ? 's' : '');
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Is this code will work based on the midnight time. It seems like the same code I used.

Comment: I edit my code, i will get midnight of postdate and + 1 day to 12h AM and then compare it with now. and i think we had better use DateTime()

Comment: hi, thank you. Seems to be this is what I need. I'll accept the answer once its verified. Thank you very much.

Comment: Np Arun. glad to help you